# Accessing MongoDB Documents Properties in ExpressJS App

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have the following code and I am trying to fetch documents from the MongoDb database and display the first name property of each document. For some reason I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined
```

Here is my app.js implementation:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var assert = require('assert');
var db = {}
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/bank';
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  this.db = db;
  console.log("Connected correctly to server.");
  db.close();
});

app.get('/customers',function(req,res){

  console.log("customers")

  this.db.open()

  var documents = this.db.collection("customers").find()

  documents[0].firstName // how to access the first name property

  this.db.close()

  res.send("fetching customers")

})
```

Comment: print documents what output you get ?

Answer (score 0):

What can i see in code is this.
you have a global scope variable .
var db = {};
and then you are doing

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
do staff
when you do

db.close();   the client is close;
})

and when you are opening the this.db.open(); next time the connection is close for mongoclient.

either don't do db.close() or

create mongoclient when you do query